# Is there a way to treat an object inside JSON as a String?

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I'm working in Java, and I have some JSON that is kinda like this:

```
{
    "objectList" : [{...}, {...}, ...], 
    "metadata" : {...}    
}
```

What I want to do is get the list and objects as JSON strings. So basically, I want to deserialize this JSON into an object like this:

```
{
    "objectList" : "[{...}, {...}, ...]", 
    "metadata" : "{...}"    
}
```

So I can do further processing on those strings.

What's the best way to do this?

I'm hesitant to try to use String parsing to extract the data I need since the values inside those objects may affect how it's being parsed.

Comment: Why do you think it would be easier to process the data if it's a string, rather than a parsed, structured value? What's the further processing you would like to do?

Comment: @aman This is Java, not JavaScript!

Comment: @aman I need to convert the objects inside a JSON object to string type, not convert an entire JSON object to string

Comment: @JBNizet  I have classes for the various types of metadata objects, so I want to deserialize it into the more specific form (eg, Video metadata vs activity metadata). Those types of metadata contain different fields, so I want to get the string for the metadata object, determine the type of metadata it is, and then deserialize into the desired metadata type.

Comment: Then parse it to a JSONObject (or whatever generic class your parser uses), and then ask the parser to parse that JSONObject to your class. Or read the documentation of your JSON parser to allow parsing it to the right class directly. Jackson can use a field value to decide what class it should create: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html. This example is a typical example of the XY problem: instead of asking for the solution you think is the right one, ask how to solve the actual problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use some JSON-parsing library (such as Gson) to turn your JSON into a `JsonObject`. You can then simply get the value of `objectList` as a `String` using `JsonObject#getAsString`:

```
String json = "{\n" +
              "    \"objectList\" : \"[{...}, {...}, ...]\", \n" +
              "    \"metadata\" : \"{...}\"    \n" +
              "}";

JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);

System.out.println(jsonObject.get("objectList").getAsString());
```

Output:

```
[{...}, {...}, ...]
```

Comment: Ah, this looks like a good approach. Do you know if there's a way to do this with Jackson Object Mapper?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I've never used Jackson; I probably won't be able to help any further with that.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll look further into it, but this looks like the best approach. Thanks!